# Django sitemap set custom paginate size?

Tags: django

So I'm using Django (1.11)'s sitemap framework and I need to add about 3.6m records into a sitemap.

Django's built-in index sitemap automatically creates a paginated version of the sitemap.  I believe each paginated sitemap page contains up to 50000 records.  That is too big and takes too long to load.

Is there some way to set a custom number of records contained within each paginated sitemap page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit from [Sitemap class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py#L52) and rewrite the `limit` property